# Notepad++ regex How to Replace third occurrence of slash & bypass the first and seconds?

Tags: regex, replace, find, match, notepad

I have strings as below.
`ABC//DEG//IJK//LMN//OPQ//rstuvwxyz`
`BCA//EGD//JKI//MNL//PQO//stuvwxyzr`
`ACB//DGE//IJK//LNM//OQP//rstuvwxyz`
`ABC//DEG//IJK//LMN//OPQ//rstuvwxyz`
`CAB//GDE//KIJ//NLM//QOP//rstuvwxyz`
`BAC//EDG//JIK//MLN//POQ//rstuvwxyz`

I want it to be like this,

`ABC//DEG//IJK\\LMN//OPQ//rstuvwxyz`
`BCA//EGD//JKI\\MNL//PQO//stuvwxyzr`
`ACB//DGE//IJK\\LNM//OQP//rstuvwxyz`
`ABC//DEG//IJK\\LMN//OPQ//rstuvwxyz`
`CAB//GDE//KIJ\\NLM//QOP//rstuvwxyz`
`BAC//EDG//JIK\\MLN//POQ//rstuvwxyz`

I have tried
Find what `^.+?\K//`
Replace with: `\\\\`
But this will only change the first occurrence of slash,,,
And I have tried this,
Find what: `^.+\K//`
Replace with: `\\\\`
And this will replace the final slash at the end of every lines ..
I tried also {3} curly brackets with numbers, but no benifits....
Thanks in advance for your helps....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:.*?\K//){3}
```

Replace with `\\\\`. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/8OT97B/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:.*?\K//){3}` - three occurrences of any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, then  `\K` (match reset operator) discards all the text matched so far and then `//` substring is only kept in the match value.

See the demo and settings screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I changed the number in brackets to 4 and it changed the last slash, working as I wanted, but the numbers in brackets doesn't match exactly .... is there a fix for this?

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah What numbers do not match exactly? What fix do you mean?

Comment: For example if I put 1 in brackets with the same regex,  it will change first occurrence and if two,  so it will bypass first and replace second occurrence and so on ,, but with your regex if I put 2 in brackets it will change third occurrences,  if there is fixing it will be great, otherwise I'm accepting your reply

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah `^(?:.*?\K//){3}`?

Comment: Thanks once again, this is what I was meant,  if possible,  please change your answer with this one....

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah Yes, I have already updated it.

Comment: If possible I would give more points, but I can give you only single point

Answer (score 1):

If you have only uppercase chars A-Z as in the example data, you can use a character class `[A-Z]+`

```
^(?:[A-Z]+//){2}[A-Z]+\K//
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[A-Z]+//){2}` Repeat 2 times matching uppercase chars A-Z and `//`
- `[A-Z]+\K//` Match 1+ uppercase chars A-Z, clear the match buffer and match `//`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HmVMBR/1)

In the replacement use `\\\\`

Comment: @ bird    The correct form of your regex is `^(?:[A-Z]+\K//){2}` ,,,, now to change numbers in brackets to any desired digits, eg ,,, from 1 Upton 5 it will replace that slashes numbers in row,,,, no worry I upvoted your answer as well,  but Viktor was first and amazingly correct as I meant...